# Understanding result of indexed access types and extends

Tags: typescript

How does the indexed access type work when combined with `extends` keyword?

I can't explain why is result of following `false`:

```
type Test<T extends readonly any[]> =  T[number] extends true ? true: false
type R = Test<[true,true,false]>
```

Result:

```
false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's go through this step by step.

`T[number]` will evaluate to `true | true | false` if `T` is `[true,true,false]`. TypeScript conveniently collapses this union down to just `boolean`.

`boolean` does *not* extend `true`, so the conditional evaluates to the false branch returning `false`.

---

You may have assumed that the union would be [distributed](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) over the conditional. But `T[number]` is not a naked generic type. No distribution takes place.

Comment: Thanks, related question, do you know If I make this modification: `type Test2<T extends readonly any[], I = T[number] > =  I extends true ? true: false`, why is result `boolean` now? If we pass same parameters to `Test2` as to `Test`.

Comment: `I` is a naked generic type which holds a union. Because of that, the conditional distributes over the elements of the union. You can imagine that each element of the union get sent through the conditional individually and the results are put together as a union in the end.

Comment: ok thanks I was not sure if `I` was naked because `T[number]` was assigned to it.